# Hosting xamlx Workflow service in IIS 7.5 errors out

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I created the most basic webservice using the Receive/SendReply with WWF 4 (.Net 4). I am not posting the code since the problem is related with deployment.

The documentation and therefore my expectation is that the xamlx file and web.config file along with the dll files have to be copied to the IIS application and bin folders, which I have done. The service works fine when launched via Visual Studio however when I copy the files to the IIS folder, it gives the following error.

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

I have checked against the web.config provided in the WWF samples and find that they are the same, however I am posting the file here.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I noticed that there is no mapping of *.xamlx in the handler mappings and there is no C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll module in the modules list. I found these on another machine. The question then becomes whey is it missing on my machine and how can I install it? I am using Windows Ultimate 7 and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on Maurice's comment:

You should run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` as an **administrator**.

I had this file in: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

After executing it (it took around 5 seconds) I had all the mappings needed for the workflow to run.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the httpHandler for the workflows. Normally this is in your machine web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.xaml.hosting"
                  type="System.Xaml.Hosting.Configuration.XamlHostingSectionGroup, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <section name="httpHandlers"
               type="System.Xaml.Hosting.Configuration.XamlHostingSection, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.xaml.hosting>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add xamlRootElementType="System.ServiceModel.Activities.WorkflowService, System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           httpHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.Activities.Activation.ServiceModelActivitiesActivationHandlerAsync, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add xamlRootElementType="System.Activities.Activity, System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           httpHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.Activities.Activation.ServiceModelActivitiesActivationHandlerAsync, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.xaml.hosting>
```

Comment: I reinstalled .net Framework 4 and it added the Module and module mapping for *.xamlx files in IIS. The services just began to work. Darn, what a waste of time figuring it out.

Comment: Was IIS installed after .NET 4 on the machine in question? In that case running aspnet_regiis.exe should fix the problem.

Comment: Yes IIS was installed after .Net 4 and that was the problem. However I had others try out the aspnet_regiis but they were not successful and eventually reinstalled .Net 4.